# Error could not find function "pull" in R

Tags: r, error-handling, event-log

I want to make an eventlog object in R with the bupaR / edeaR package. But I get an error message:

> Error in function_list[i] : could not find function "pull"

Function `pull` is from the package `git2r`, but I dont even need this package to make an eventlog. Even when I activate package `git2r` and try to do the same, another error message comes up:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘pull’ for signature ‘"eventlog"’.

This is my code:

```
total2 <- eventlog(eventlog = total, 
          case_id = "Klantnummer",
          activity_id = "activiteit",
          activity_instance_id = "activiteit_id",
          lifecycle_id = "status",
          timestamp = "datum_beoordeling",
          resource_id = "Kanaal")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Btw: The object "total" is a dataframe with only these 6 variables

Comment: Please make a reproducible example.

Comment: I suspect another package is masking a function (I suspect dplyr). Look at which packages are loaded and test if any of these might cause the issue.

Comment: Yes, dplyr is always causing trouble :(. When I try to detach the package it says: ‘dplyr’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘dplyr’ is imported by ‘petrinetR’, ‘xesreadR’, ‘processmonitR’, ‘edeaR’, ‘bupaR’ so cannot be unloaded

Answer (score 1):

You should update your dplyr-version to 0.7.0 which includes the pull function. It seems that bupaR does not specifically states this dependency.